# How to exclude certain HTML class from JS code

Tags: javascript

This JavaScript code makes tables responsive:

```
/* Credits:
    https://gist.github.com/jpen365/f34bbff7d9db99f912e1e75193071718 */

var headertext = [];
var headers = document.querySelectorAll("thead");
var tablebody = document.querySelectorAll("tbody");

for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
    headertext[i]=[];
    for (var j = 0, headrow; headrow = headers[i].rows[0].cells[j]; j++) {
      var current = headrow;
      headertext[i].push(current.textContent);
      }
} 

for (var h = 0, tbody; tbody = tablebody[h]; h++) {
    for (var i = 0, row; row = tbody.rows[i]; i++) {
      for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
        col.setAttribute("data-th", headertext[h][j]);
      } 
    }
}
```

My question is how to exclude tables using class all tables with this class `is-style-stripes` for example this table:

```
<table class="wp-block-table aligncenter is-style-stripes">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th>Company</th><td>Amazon</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Company</th><td>Google</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get all tables without class you can use

```
document.querySelectorAll("table:not(.is-style-stripes)")
```

You will get all tables without that class

If you want tables with this class just use

```
document.querySelectorAll("table.is-style-stripes")
```

Then you can search for it's `tbody` or `thead` like
`table.querySelectorAll("tbody")`

Comment: You can combine them: `document.querySelectorAll("table:not(.is-style-stripes) tbody")`